# Why aren't these images showing?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

On my website, I have a slider type thing at the top of the page. Each slide page has a little icon of stitch from lilo and stitch, but the only icon that shows up is the icon on the default slider (welcome slider).... why is this?

EDIT: I can't get the code to work, but to see the issue you're going to have to view the source. The section with the images inside it is the div with the id of container, right after the thumbs code which is inside the div with the id of slidebox.

The website URL is http://-respawn.tumblr.com

Comment: your link is broken/borked - can you post a working one please?

Comment: Not exactly related to the question but you might wanna check your html code, you have two `<script>` tags including jquery in your page.

Comment: @sitnik - that url doesn't load in my browser and if I remove the dash I end up on a site which doesn't even have a **slider type thing** - what is the correct url?

Comment: @Stephen that URL IS the correct url. it has to have to dash or it will not work. Some computers don't accept dashes in front of urls... it seems as though you have one of those computers.

Comment: ok, after a quick google I see that this is something a lot of tumblr users are doing to their URLs right now. I'm surprised anyone would want a URL that might not work on the girl next door's computer but it's your site and you're well within your rights to put these kinds of barriers in place to prevent arbitrary members of the public from viewing it. I quite like the idea now that I think of it. It's a really clever way to cut down on all that pesky _traffic/advertising-revenue/future-sales_ etc etc

Comment: Like @sitnik already tried to explain, you're including jQuery twice on the page and that is never good.

Comment: Ok, _why_ are people prefixing their URLs with dashes?

Answer (score 2):

The first two images (purple animal) show up ok - the next 3 don't.

Your first two images load as:

```
http://dl3.glitter-graphics.net/pub/1003/1003453kf9pkci1jl.gif

http://dl6.glitter-graphics.net/pub/600/600346jg80ocmixs.gif
```

while the next 3 are just a 1x1 empty image called grey.gif so obviously it won't show anything.

```
http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/RSvlio0k5/grey.gif

http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/RSvlio0k5/grey.gif

http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/RSvlio0k5/grey.gif
```

No idea where you calling that from but that is why they won't show.

EDIT: Another funny thing i noticed - if you quickly scroll up and down your browser the images will load since the code changes from:

```
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/RSvlio0k5/grey.gif" style="float: left; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 7px; " original="http://dl6.glitter-graphics.net/pub/2000/2000286qs6oy6afoc.gif">
```

to

```
<img src="http://dl6.glitter-graphics.net/pub/2000/2000286qs6oy6afoc.gif" style="float: left; margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 7px; display: block; " original="http://dl6.glitter-graphics.net/pub/2000/2000286qs6oy6afoc.gif">
```

Seems like what thumblr does is to load first a dummy image and than set the `display:block`. You will have to find out what script is causing that.

Comment: Um, when I go to customize, all the images are valid images from glitter-graphics..

Comment: ITS LAZY LOAD! THATS PROBABLY WHY! Lemme  fix that, one second! :D

Comment: @James Charless Dickinson - image links are ok - seems like thumblr has some script messing with preloading or something - can't help you more than this.

Comment: No, you fixed it! Thank you SO much! :D

Comment: Yeah IK, I fixed the lazy load! You ROCK!: D

Comment: @James Charless Dickinson - Nah I code. If this helped you fix it dunno why you accepted other answer but ok. Important that it's fixed.

Comment: @easwee let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2023/discussion-between-james-charless-dickinson-and-easwee)

Answer (score 0):

Something must have happened when you were uploading your images to tumblr. I'd suggest creating a post, clicking on the "+Upload photo" button, selecting the `.gif`s that you want to use in your slider, upload them into a post and then select the image, and click on the little image icon. This will open a pop-up window with a URL in it, copy that URL and paste it as the source for your image. This way tumblr will host your images and you can use them in your slider.

Comment: For some reason the styling on your `img`s is different for each. Not just the values, but the properties used. It could have something to do with that.

Comment: Also, your `img` tags aren't closed anywhere.

Comment: Since when do you have to close img tags? :?

Comment: @James Charless Dickinson Self closing `<img />` - but that is not really important since the browser manages to parse it anyway. It's more for standard compliance.

Comment: It wasn't your problem, but it's usually a best practice thing. You just have to close it as `<img />`.